# Custom Columns in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

I would like to be able add custom columns in Rhythmbox for things like "Version" and "Grouping".  Is there a .ui file in /usr/share/rhythmbox or elsewhere that I need to edit in order to do this; and if so which one.  I've figured out how to add a checkbox in the preferences menu for such a thing, but I can't figure how to add a column that pulls the correct data from the tags.

Comment: are you coding some sort of plugin?  Perhaps give a bit more details of what and how you are making changes.  Are you attempting to change the library view or are you making your own custom view?

Comment: Out of the box, Rhythmbox ignores the Grouping and Version tags.  You can't add columns for these tags or view them when you look at a song's Properties.  I would like to add the ability to view this information (and hence sort by it).